# How can I insert CSS style into value=""?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I have done is try to pass a CSS property to a new HTML page by using a `<form>` tag.

So I had this code:

```css
#a {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<form action="newpage.html" method="GET" target="_parent">
  <input type="hidden" name="fontsize" id="fontsize" value="font-size property of #a here" />
  <button>CONTINUE</button>
</form>
```

How can I pass the `font-size` of `#a` to the `value` attribute of the `<input>` tag?

Comment: Do you mean you want the default value of the input tag to be the font size?

Comment: yes, my bad there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getComputedStyle` to get the values of all CSS properties of an element. Then you can use `getPropertyValue` to get the value of the property you are looking for. Now you just have to pass the value to the value of the input field.

Here is an example:

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  var el = document.getElementById('a'),
      style = window.getComputedStyle(el),
      fontSize = style.getPropertyValue('font-size');
  this.querySelector('input[name="fontsize"]').value = fontSize;
  console.log(fontSize)
  e.preventDefault()
})
```

```css
#a {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">Hello</div>
<form action="newpage.html" method="GET" target="_parent">
  <input type="hidden" name="fontsize" id="fontsize" value="" />
  <button>CONTINUE</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Cheers man! Although it wasn't actually something I need, but it help to solve my problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, maybe i did not read your question correctly, my bad. Glad to hear that you figured it out yourself. :)